# Adding custom hover text using json to a SharePoint list column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a SharePoint list which has a Title column and a Description. The Description column is a multi-line text field.

I would like to not display the Description column and instead show the relevant Description when moving the cursor over the Title field.

I've found JSON code to display a card or image when hovering over a field but I'm not sure how to do something similar with just a string of text.

I'm guessing it's fairly easy for someone who knows what they are doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this and customize to suit your need

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "font-size": "12px"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "customCardProps": {
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "[$Description]",
      "style": {
        "font-size": "12px",
        "color": "green",
        "padding": "5px"
      }
    },
    "openOnEvent": "hover",
    "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
    "isBeakVisible": true,
    "beakStyle": {
      "backgroundColor": "white"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks you!

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark the question as **answered**

Comment: @MatiurRahman. a similar question, If you can help there, that would b emuch appreciated. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/287335/tooltip-column-on-hover-a-column-in-sharepoint-list-using-json-modern-list-view