# tooltip column on hover a column in SharePoint List Using JSON- Modern List View

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

I need to show the description of column as a tooltip when a user hover a mouse on a column, I am doing this based on [Adding custom hover text using json to a SharePoint list column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/285931/adding-custom-hover-text-using-json-to-a-sharepoint-list-column/285934#285934)

But I need to enter the description manually rather than reading the description of the column that I put earlier for that column in the Description textbox.

see below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I change "txtContent": "[$Description]", to "txtContent": "This is the desciption", it works fine, is there any way to fix the previous issue and get the description rather than entering a new description here as txt
[image]

Comment: Please note that [$Decription] in the example is a **separate** column, and hovering on the [Title] column values is showing values from the [$Description] column. As I understood your requirements, you need to show the **Description**, which is meta data, of column [Name]. There's a way to show column's meta data. However, my testing didn't work for "Description", but worked for "DisplayName", that is, [!Project.DisplayName] **worked** but [!Project.Description] did **not** worked. Here [Project] is a custom column, and you can refer meta data in JSON using  a **!** char

Comment: Thank you, I realized the Prj.Description vs meta description in the middle of trying the approach you suggested in the previous answered example. So, I was trying to get the meta data description as you highlighted and also shown by the above screenshots to avoid any confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on MS JSON reference guide at [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting), we should be able to show meta data in column formatting.

**[!FieldName]**

*In column and view formatting, you can refer to any field's metadata by specifying the internal name of the field surrounded by square brackets and preceded by a exclamation mark: [!InternalName].
Currently field's display name is available in this metadata, and can be accessed using DisplayName property: [!SalesLead.DisplayName].*

However, it didn't work for me for the **Description**.
My testing worked for [!Project.DisplayName], but didn't work for [!Project.Description]
(here, Project is a custom column).

Comment: thx a lot,  based on your description, So, I guess I have to manually type the description in two different places: JSON formatting and the "Description" of the column

Comment: I also checked the src code for both view and when we are editing the column properties to see whether I can see the internal name of Description, no success, when in editing mode, I was able to see a derived version of description but "txtContent": "[!Project_x0020_Name.__description__]" did not work too –

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no way to get the column description in JSON column formatting. You have to manually type the description in the json code.

Comment: thx Michael, upvoted, thx for confirming